# compare 3 columns between 2 worksheets and pull across a 4th columns from sheet 1 to sheet 2 where they match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i am using the latest version of excel inside office365.

I need to compare 3 columns in my data (worksheet1) with 3 columns in a lookup table (worksheet2)
where the columns match i need to pull the data from a 4th column in worksheet2 into worksheet1

can somebody send me the function to make this work please

Many thanks from a very frustrated excel noob :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: any sample data?

Comment: How do i add sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to combine the data in each of the three column sets and add a little something to make sure things keep their "fact of being columns" relationship. Each of the following formulas will work just fine for you:

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A1:A8&"|"&B1:B8&"|"&C1:C8,Sheet2!A1:A8&"|"&Sheet2!B1:B8&"|"&Sheet2!C1:C8,Sheet2!D1:D8),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!D1:D8,MATCH(A1:A8&"|"&B1:B8&"|"&C1:C8,Sheet2!A1:A8&"|"&Sheet2!B1:B8&"|"&Sheet2!C1:C8,0)),"")

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A8&"|"&B1:B8&"|"&C1:C8,CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet2!A1:A8&"|"&Sheet2!B1:B8&"|"&Sheet2!C1:C8,Sheet2!D1:D8),2,FALSE),"")

=IF(A1:A8&"|"&B1:B8&"|"&C1:C8=Sheet2!A1:A8&"|"&Sheet2!B1:B8&"|"&Sheet2!C1:C8,Sheet2!D1:D8,"")
```

The first uses the modern `XLOOKUP()`, the second is a standard `INDEX/MATCH` formula, the third is a way to do it with `VLOOKUP()`, and the fourth is a simple "does this equal that?" `IF()` test that returns a value if TRUE and does not if FALSE.

`XLOOKUP()` almost always completely replaces `INDEX/MATCH` formula with a more straightforward looking formula, one easier to understand especially for new users and for someone taking over another person's spreadsheet. Not "always" but just "almost always." I find maybe 10% of the time it does not serve as well, but other folks seem to never have uses in which it does not.

The three lookup formulas will return errors for non-matching results so each of them is wrapped with the `IFERROR()` function to return a blank if there is no match.

Each of the four formulas takes the three columns of data on each sheet and combines  them together to have a single value to look up. There are various COMMON ways to do the joining:

1. Literally `JOIN` them as done here. One uses the `&` as the union operator to put the pieces together.
2. Use the `CONCATENATE()` function.
3. Use the `CONCAT()` function.
4. Use the `TEXTJOIN()` function.

For simple things like this, I just use #1. It is faster than any function, supposedly, so that was nice when I was first doing spreadsheets. Things stick, eh? `CONCATENATE()` is no easier or harder and just as simple and straightforward. `CONCAT()` and `TEXTJOIN()` would work here, preferably the latter, except... the latter flat won't work in a single `SPILL` function at the top of the column filling down for you automatically. You'd have to copy and paste down the column. And do more of that when new entries occur. Deal with funny things if a row is deleted. `CONCAT()` can be made to work in a `SPILL` way, usually, but this time it would take cleverness I saw no reason to spend time on.

The approaches in the four formulas DO all `SPILL` so it's one and done.

So, what about the business of maintaining column relationships? What's that even mean, right? Say you have two columns you're putting together for a lookup. One row in the lookup data has "person" in column 1 and "al" in column 2. Simply combining them gives "personal" — just fine so far. In the data being looked through, a row has "personal" in column 1 and a blank in column 2. Simply combining them gives "personal"... Excel would consider the lookup value to have been found, it's a match! But it isn't. No information about how the data appeared in the two sources has been kept to help out. If, though, you combine the first column plus a not much used character (I used the `|` character) plus the second column, you compare "person|al" to "personal|" and Excel can see they are not a match. That character let you combine the values so you can look things up as if they are a single value, but maintained their true nature.

The `VLOOKUP()` formula uses a trick to let you make a virtual table in the formula out of the combined three columns (column "1" in the virtual table) and the column with the value you want to get (column 2 in the virtual table). It uses the `CHOOSE()` function with the two columns needed, the combined three columns now being one of them and the results column being the second, and a trick to make Excel give you BOTH columns, "choosing" both columns instead of what you'd think, that of choosing one or the other. The trick is the `{1,2}` you see instead of either a `1` or `2` (by themselves, and no curly braces). The curly braces make it what Excel calls an `array constant` and Excel will act on both of the values inside it so you "get two for the price of one." (They can be however long you need. And do not have to be in order, or only use a value once:  `{3,1,5,5,5,8,22,27,1,2,3}` would be just fine if you had at least 27 columns to choose from. Here you just need the two.)

So Excel makes a virtual two column table in the function and you tell it to return column 2 to Sheet1.

There ARE quite a few other ways to do this too. Most are "OG" methods for when Excel was much harder to do things with, and involve some whacky looking things. Once you do them a few times, they are simple (sort of) and straightforward (sort of), but understandable. They are just strange things to grasp at first and they make virtual array constants that are limited in length by Excel so if you have many rows and long-ish data in each of the three columns, they can fail. And since they could fail 6,000 or 30,000 rows in, you might not notice right off. Do a lot of work, then see you have to begin again.

Limitations exist with `VLOOKUP()` and `MATCH()` (so in the `INDEX/MATCH` formula). There is a limit by Excel of looking only at the first 256 characters for each combination value. So if you have long-ish values in the three columns, you might have troubles. The former has a workaround that involves virtual array constants so the same limits as those really odd approaches I mentioned, and the new `XMATCH()` overcomes `MATCH()`'s limits. But if using a new function, why not just go straight to `XLOOKUP()`, right? Something to remember though when `XLOOKUP()` just won't fit your needs.

So, you're new to this. I will mention one other function that would be of interest in many cases of this kind but that will NOT work for you here:  `FILTER()`.

`FILTER()` would get you a list without blanks in it. So it won't work here because it would put values in rows that don't have matches. It's more of a "return everything that matched, but don't bother matching the returns up to the data they matched on. VERY unsuitable here, but when you need a collection of data, and the blanks would actually be a problem, `FILTER()` is insanely handy. Something you should look at fairly soon for solving problems you will likely encounter.